# Запрос sql по трём таблицам

Tags: mysql, sql

**Вывести ФИО владельцев, ни одна лошадь которых не участвовала в заезде №1.**

*Что здесь не правильно ?*

```
    "SELECT * FROM horseowner JOIN horsedata ON horseowner.idowner = 
horsedata.numberownerhorse JOIN racing ON horsedata.idhorse = 
racing.namberracinghorse WHERE racing.idracing NOT IN(1)"
```

**есть 3 таблицы "horseowner", "horsedata", "racing"**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так,

```
SELECT distinct horseowner.fioowner
 FROM horseowner 
  LEFT JOIN horsedata 
   ON horseowner.idowner = horsedata.numberownerhorse 
  LEFT JOIN racing 
   ON horsedata.idhorse = racing.namberracinghorse
WHERE racing.idracing IS NULL
```

Конечно тут выведет и тех у которых нет лошади и вовсе, но чтоб у хозяина была лошадь нужно первый жоин был иннер

Comment: Спасибо большое!